# How to do type checking while using Django?

Tags: python, django

There are linters that support type checking, however they become a mess in a Django project. Is there any way to have type checking for where I define type hints, but not do it for all the Django bits and pieces?

I'm using Conda and VS Code.

Comment: *PyCharm Professional* has a Django extension that has more "understanding" how Django works, and thus can do more type hinting.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to annotate the code, like:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    a = models.IntegerField()
```

But Django makes extensive use of *meta-classes*, *descriptors*, `__getattr__` and other magic, that makes it hard for code analysis tools to understand how it works, just by analyzing the code.

*PyCharm Professional* has a Django extension which has encoded some Django knowledge, and thus instead of doing code analysis has some rules that thus can help understand parts of the core of Django. While not perfect, it can help with type analysis, etc.